# Saving record to mysql database using php

Tags: php, mysql

I seem to be having a problem with saving record directly into my database. I have a richtextarea on one of my website page. when i copy two(2) pages article from ms word document and paste on the richtextarea, trying to save it, it will generate error, except about ten lines of document that can be saved.

But using localhost i can save as many pages i copied from ms word document and paste on the richtextarea.
I think maybe i need some kind of permission from my web hosting company before saving large file content into database. Pls help me!!!

Comment: You are being very vague. Please add more information, and code!

Comment: Please show relevant parts of your code. Do you escape the input?

Answer (score 0):

You're right, before two month we had the same issue. you need permission from your web hosting company to modify the configuration in your server's php.ini, you have to configure the following two configuration directives that's,

```
post_max_size
max_execution_time
```

For more reference:

[post_max_size Reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size)

[max_execution_time Reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time)

Comment: i have already contacted my webhost, and waiting for their reply.

Comment: i got an answer from then. this is what they send to me

Comment: Dear Sir,

Your need to set Write Permissions on the folder where your application is uploading the files so that your application can save the files to disk.    does this answer seem to be the solution? i think not, cos i am saving to database and uploading to a folder. pls advise.

Comment: yes that answer is not to be a solution of your problem. what you need to do is rise the **token** to your technical team in your webhost, and tell that i want to edit that's increase my server's  post_max_size  and max_execution_time  in php.ini file, they only able to do this,  what they want is need a permission from you to edit php.ini file.

Comment: tnx bro! my host seemd to have modified the configuration in php.ini file. coz i previosly gave them permission as you suggested before. thanx man. the prob is solved. am happy now. grateful enof for all the contributions so far.